# How to pass a function with parameters being partially fixed to a higher-order function?

Tags: functional-programming, partial, dolphindb

I want to pass function `ols` to the higher-order function `moving` (or `rolling`) as an argument with the first argument (the dependent variable) of `ols` fixed.  For example, I have `ols([1,2], [x(n),x(n-1),x(n-2),x(n-3)])`

where

- the dependent variable y is fixed as [1,2]
- x(n) is a vector generated from the nth rolling window over x.

Answer (score 0):

In your example of partial application, the fixed input parameter is a vector. Try this script:

```
defg getR2(x,y){
    return ols(y, x, true, 2).RegressionStat[0,1]
}
x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
y = 1 2
moving(getR2{,y},x, 2)
```

output:

```
offset  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0           1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

You can also fix the input parameters that are matrices in a partial application. For example:

```
defg getR2(x,y){
    return ols(x,y,,2).RegressionStat[0,1]
}
x = matrix([1 2 3],[4,5,6])
y = matrix([1 2 3],[4,5,6])
each(def(m,n) -> moving(getR2, [m,n], 2), x, y)
```

output:

```
col1    col2
    
1   1
1   1
```